# Sendmail - use custom port for specific domains

Tags: linux, email, centos, smtp, sendmail

CentOS 5.x | SendMail

Hi,

I need to route email for specific domains to a custom port on a downstream server.  Is there an easy way of doing this? I came across various instructions describing how to do this if I set my local sendmail listening interface to a different port but I don't want to do this.

In short, I want my local sendmail MTA to still listen on port 25 but to send mail for foo.com to MTA 123.123.123.123 on port 2525.

-M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the mailertable add to your /etc/mail/mailertable

```
domain_name    smtp[123.123.123.123:2525]
```

Then run

```
make -C /etc/mail
```

Answer (score 1):

For my version of sendmail, the correct format is:

```
domain_name    smtp:[123.123.123.123]:2525
```

Note: added a colon after "smtp" making it "smtp:", and moved the second right bracket after the IP address, and before the ":2525".